# Is there any simple, free tool to track VM dependancies to linked-clones in VMWare?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-workstation, clone

We have a few "base installations" of various OS environments that we use to create linked clones in VMware Workstation. Sometimes, to save space and because speed is of secondary importance, those linked-clones are also use to create other linked-clones and over time it's becoming difficult to track the whole linked-clones dependancy tree.  I know there is a flag in Workstation that one can set to mark the VM as "used for cloning" but it's a manual process and a bit annoying (and error prone) to keep up to date.

It would be quite simple to write a Perl script or something similar to follow the dependancy tree and display it but I figure someone out there must already have done that.  Has anyone seen such a tool?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a tool. You could check the vmdk descriptors for the parameter "parentfilenamehint" which shows the parent of the snapshot in the CID chain